# Chat pings are not turning into notifications

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, ping

I was mentioned in [this message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6062822#6062822) while I was not in the chat room. Usually, this should become a notification after 15 minutes.

However, I didn't get any notification as can be seen in this screenshot:

> [image]

As you can see, I do get notifications from comments and from chat rooms in Stack Overflow.

Also, this is not the first time. For long time I don't get notification from the chat room mentioned in the link above, while I do get notifications from Stack Overflow room. Possibly a bug?

Comment: Were you definitely not in the chat room (as in you explicitly left the room)? Or did you just close the tab? I do know it takes a few minutes (not sure how long) for you to actually leave the room after closing the tab. Maybe that is a contributing factor?

Comment: @JasonC The message was posted like 9 hours ago. I am sure my laptop was shut down 14-15 hours ago from now, and I switched it on at like 12 hours ago from now, but I only entered the room about 2-3 hours ago from now. I posted this message rightaway when I entered: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6063127#6063127

Comment: There are a lot of blokes on SE who will react to this "bug" with a loud YAY. :)

Comment: @Jason even if he was in the room, unread pings are turned into notifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939/31259
Point 3 looks like the answer to your question because you got pinged with '@ber':

> @Ton will notify you if you've been in the room in the past two days and there's no other user for whom this would be a better match, e.g. someone called "Ton" who has been there within the past seven days (that's 1.) or someone called "Ton Ynnuf" who has been there within the past two days (that's 2.).

Based on the transcript, you hadn't been in the room for 2 days, so no notification.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JoErNanO's advice, I logged out and logged in back, and tested it again with @JoE and @Sha, and I started receiving notifications again.

Comment: Doesn't seems a real bug to me (-__-)